# sonar command for two files

Tags: sonarqube

Does any one know a command to run multiple files in sonar, I don't want to run

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

I have some 3-4 files which i want to run at a time, may be by comma separated, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and use it to automate the building of your 3-4 Maven projects.

There is also a [Sonar plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin) for Jenkins which makes it even simpler to run Sonar